# Javascript - Iterator confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

In this simple code, the `console.log(names.next().value);` if called twice the array index increases. I'm not sure how its doing that since I think it should always start with 0 so it should have returned the same value.

Can someone explain how it is doing that?

```js
// Iterator Example
function nameIterator(names) {
  let nextIndex = 0;
  console.log(nextIndex);

  return {
    next: function() {
      return nextIndex < names.length ? {
        value: names[nextIndex++],
        done: false
      } : {
        done: true
      }
    }
  }
}

// Create an array of names
const namesArr = ['Brad', 'Sara', 'John'];
// Init iterator and pass in the names array
const names = nameIterator(namesArr);

console.log(names.next().value);
console.log(names.next().value);
console.log(names.next().value);
console.log(names.next());
```

Output:

```
Brad
Sara
John
Object : {done: true}
```

Comment: And why you do expect it to start from 0? You are not calling the nameIterator . You called it once which returned you the next() method  and then you are called next() method repeatedly and index value is getting incremented in that .

Comment: But, you're increasing the index every time you call the function `next()`, what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `next()` uses `nextIndex` property present in your `nameIterator()` function.

`next()` doesn't have a separate copy of `nextIndex` property available to itself. So when you do `nextIndex++` in your `next()` method, it actually updates the `nextIndex` that we have in `nameIterator()`, and the next time you call `next()`, you'll access this updated `nextIndex` only.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the following line in the code.

```
names[nextIndex++]
```

This line selects the index in the `names` value and then increases the value of `nextIndex` with one, but only after it has selected the key. See it in the example below to see what it outputs.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let index = 0;

console.log(arr[index++]);
console.log(arr[index++]);
console.log(arr[index++]);
```

So the `nextIndex` increments with every time you call the `next()` method and keeps going until the `nextIndex` value reaches a threshold.

Comment: Upvoted. This explained me the index question I had in mind

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call the function `next`, the index it's incremented by 1 `->` `nextIndex++`.

You can pass a flag indicating you want the current index value as follow:

```js
// Iterator Example
function nameIterator(names) {
  let nextIndex = 0;
  return {
    next: function(current) {      
      let index;
      if (current) {
        index = (nextIndex < names.length ? nextIndex : names.length) - 1;
      } else {
        index = nextIndex++;
      }
      
      return index < names.length ? {
        value: names[index],
        done: false
      } : {
        done: true
      }
    }
  }
}

// Create an array of names
const namesArr = ['Brad', 'Sara', 'John'];
// Init iterator and pass in the names array
const names = nameIterator(namesArr);

console.log(names.next().value);
console.log(names.next(true).value);
console.log(names.next(true).value);
console.log(names.next(true).value);
console.log(names.next().value);
console.log(names.next(true).value);
console.log(names.next().value);
console.log(names.next());
console.log(names.next(true).value);
console.log(names.next());
```